# Como volver a suscribirse a una peticion Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola tengo un componente padre que es un formulario, el cual cuando agrege un usuario deberia mostrarlo a la derecha de la pantalla en un sidebar que es un componente hijo. El problema es que cuando inserto en la base de datos, no actualiza el listado de usuarios.
Solo se actualiza cuando recargo la pagina.
Entonces trate de volver a cargar a los usuarios cuando inserto con un metodo que vuelva a llamar al metodo de listar usuarios de la base de datos, pero aun asi no se refresca la vista del hijo.

Este es mi HTML del componente padre :

```
  <form [formGroup]="form">
   ........ 
  <button (click)="OnSubmit()" >Agregar Usuario</button>
  </form>
  <app-sidebar [users]="users"></app-sidebar>
```

Este es mi TS la funcion click donde Agrego los usuarios:

```
users = [];
constructor(private userService:UserService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(){
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
    (resp: any) => this.users = resp,
    error => console.log(error)
  )}
OnSubmit() {
 this.userService.createUser(this.data).subscribe(
    () => this.getUsers(),
    (error) => console.log(error)
 );
```

Y este es el HTML de mi componente hijo

```
<nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>USUARIOS</h3>
        </div>
        <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
            <li>Identificacion {{user.id}}</li>
            <li>Nombre: {{user.nombre}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Y este es el TS del hijo

```
 export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() users;
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
   }
}
```

Aqui tambien dejo el servicio que hago para obtener a los usuarios

```
getUsuarios(){
    return this.http.get(`localhost:8000/usuarios`);
  }
```

Comment: Prueba haciendo un `console.log` a `resp` en esta linea `(resp: any) => this.users = resp`

Answer (score 1):

En la comunicación entre componentes padre e hijo se puede compartir un arreglo, en este caso de usuarios. Cuando en el servicio se agregue un usuario solo se hace un `push` al arreglo y el componente hijo se actualiza:

Componente padre:

```
 import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user">
      <input type="button" value="agregar" (click)="agregar()"/>
    
      <hr/>
    
      <app-child-component [users]= "users">
      </app-child-component>`
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      user;
      users : any = []
    
      agregar(){
        this.users.push(this.user);
      }
    }
```

Componente hijo:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  template: `
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let u of users">{{u}}</li>
</ul>`,
})
export class ChildComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() users : any;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

[Ejemplo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ouje3l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-component%2Fchild-component.component.ts)